# Change system date on Windows using Qt

Tags: qt, date, qt4, system

What is the most appropriate method to change the system date (on Windows) programmatically using Qt4. I'm using Qt Creator 1.3.1.

Comment: There is no facility in Qt to set the system date/time. That is usually a privileged operation and is system dependent. Unless you have full control over the OS or you are writing a hardware clock utility, it is also unwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Windows API, [GetLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724338%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [SetLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724936%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
SYSTEMTIME localTime;
GetLocalTime(&localTime);

localTime.wHour = 21;
localTime.wMinute = 30;

if (SetLocalTime(&localTime) != 0)
{
    // ok
}
else
{
    // failed
}
```

Comment: I guess using API is the only option for me right now. Thanks.